# How to retrieve section IDs using Google docs API Python

Tags: python, google-docs-api

For instance, we have a document such as this -

Table Of Content

1. Introduction
   <text: A>

1.1 Background
<text: B>

1.2 Problem statement
<text: C>

2. Approach
   <text: D>

2.1.1 Outline of the algorithm
<text: E>

I need to pattern match a "string" in all of the texts in the document. For example my search string could be "REQ-". Which could match "REQ-1", "REQ-2" to "REQ-10".

Suppose if "REQ-1" was located in text:C, and "REQ-2" in text:E, then the output I am looking for is

("REQ-1", "1.2"), ("REQ-2", "2.1.1") etc

Essentially, it matches the search string, identify all matches, and for each match, returns a 2-tuple of the matched string and the "section id" in the document containing the matched string.

```
def get_creds():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            "cred_new.json", scopes=SCOPES
        )
    return credentials

def search_paragraph_element(element, search_str):
    text_run = element.get('textRun')
    if not text_run:
        return False
    res = text_run.get('content').find(search_str)
    if res != -1:
        return True
    return False


def search_structural_elements(elements, search_str):
    text = ''
    hd_1 = 0
    hd_2 = 0
    hd_3 = 0
    for value in elements:
        if 'paragraph' in value:
            if value['paragraph']['paragraphStyle']['namedStyleType'] == 'HEADING_1':
                hd_1 = hd_1 + 1
                hd_2 = 0
                hd_3 = 0
            elif value['paragraph']['paragraphStyle']['namedStyleType'] == 'HEADING_2':
                hd_2 = hd_2 + 1
                hd_3 = 0
            elif value['paragraph']['paragraphStyle']['namedStyleType'] == 'HEADING_3':
                hd_3 = hd_3 + 1
            elements = value.get('paragraph').get('elements')
            for elem in elements:
                res = search_paragraph_element(elem, search_str)
                if res is True:
                    return str(hd_1) + '.' + str(hd_2)  + '.' + str(hd_3)
    return text

def main():
    """Uses the Docs API to print out the text of a document."""
    credentials = get_creds()
    service = build("docs", "v1", credentials=credentials).documents()
    properties = service.get(documentId=REQ_DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
    doc_content = properties.get('body').get('content')
    print(search_structural_elements(doc_content, "MySearchString"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
``
```

Comment: Do you have a code you are working on?

Comment: Hi All, Have added the code

Comment: Could you explain what your current code is doing, and what specific issue you're having problems with?

Comment: @lamblichus thanks for following-up. Suppose I have a structural element (using Google docs Python API) and I am wanting to extract the "link" to the section containing that element, and obtain the link as a string. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you provide a sample Doc in order to make sure we are on the same page here?